# Parsing dictionary keys and items for graph plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following dictionary:

```
Counter({'140\n': 3098, '139\n': 1543, '138\n': 1259, '137\n': 1135, '136\n': 990, '135\n': 851, '134\n': 826, '133\n': 644, '132\n': 574, '131\n': 531, '144\n': 481, '130\n': 473, '129\n': 443, '128\n': 428, '126\n': 397, '127\n': 384, '125\n': 351, '124\n': 325, '123\n': 314, '121\n': 305, '111\n': 304, '118\n': 296, '114\n': 295, '122\n': 294, '117\n': 292, '116\n': 290, '119\n': 287, '120\n': 287, '113\n': 286, '115\n': 276, '112\n': 266, '110\n': 266, '109\n': 246, '101\n': 241, '106\n': 240, '98\n': 236, '102\n': 235, '107\n': 234, '93\n': 234, '104\n': 232, '100\n': 231, '103\n': 229, '108\n': 228, '97\n': 222, '105\n': 220, '96\n': 218, '99\n': 216, '143\n': 213, '94\n': 211, '90\n': 198, '95\n': 197, '91\n': 196, '92\n': 196, '83\n': 193, '88\n': 193, '86\n': 192, '87\n': 192, '89\n': 191, '81\n': 189, '84\n': 188, '77\n': 187, '80\n': 183, '85\n': 173, '79\n': 170, '82\n': 170, '75\n': 167, '74\n': 163, '70\n': 160, '142\n': 155, '78\n': 153, '72\n': 151, '71\n': 147, '76\n': 146, '68\n': 137, '65\n': 134, '141\n': 133, '73\n': 132, '62\n': 124, '66\n': 124, '57\n': 124, '63\n': 121, '69\n': 117, '59\n': 113, '56\n': 113, '67\n': 111, '60\n': 110, '61\n': 107, '58\n': 106, '51\n': 100, '22\n': 100, '25\n': 99, '24\n': 99, '48\n': 97, '23\n': 95, '64\n': 93, '52\n': 92, '53\n': 92, '45\n': 91, '20\n': 91, '55\n': 90, '54\n': 89, '50\n': 86, '49\n': 85, '34\n': 85, '36\n': 85, '21\n': 83, '29\n': 82, '26\n': 80, '47\n': 79, '27\n': 79, '30\n': 78, '40\n': 76, '31\n': 76, '46\n': 76, '35\n': 75, '32\n': 75, '37\n': 70, '39\n': 69, '19\n': 68, '28\n': 67, '41\n': 67, '43\n': 66, '148\n': 66, '33\n': 64, '38\n': 59, '42\n': 58, '44\n': 56, '164\n': 50, '18\n': 48, '17\n': 46, '163\n': 43, '168\n': 39, '147\n': 37, '161\n': 29, '162\n': 29, '16\n': 25, '167\n': 25, '146\n': 23, '15\n': 23, '145\n': 23, '156\n': 22, '152\n': 21, '159\n': 20, '160\n': 19, '157\n': 19, '158\n': 17, '151\n': 16, '280\n': 15, '166\n': 13, '150\n': 11, '172\n': 11, '14\n': 10, '149\n': 10, '155\n': 9, '165\n': 9, '154\n': 9, '153\n': 8, '284\n': 8, '13\n': 7, '12\n': 6, '279\n': 6, '273\n': 6, '216\n': 6, '170\n': 5, '248\n': 5, '278\n': 5, '254\n': 5, '174\n': 5, '10\n': 4, '176\n': 4, '283\n': 4, '272\n': 4, '277\n': 4, '263\n': 4, '276\n': 4, '175\n': 4, '250\n': 4, '183\n': 4, '245\n': 4, '246\n': 3, '281\n': 3, '266\n': 3, '240\n': 3, '237\n': 3, '190\n': 3, '208\n': 3, '275\n': 3, '257\n': 3, '232\n': 3, '270\n': 3, '274\n': 3, '229\n': 3, '233\n': 3, '255\n': 3, '241\n': 3, '271\n': 3, '171\n': 3, '227\n': 2, '199\n': 2, '222\n': 2, '209\n': 2, '288\n': 2, '259\n': 2, '304\n': 2, '286\n': 2, '184\n': 2, '268\n': 2, '242\n': 2, '265\n': 2, '296\n': 2, '217\n': 2, '256\n': 2, '191\n': 2, '290\n': 2, '303\n': 2, '173\n': 2, '307\n': 2, '200\n': 2, '231\n': 2, '301\n': 2, '261\n': 2, '186\n': 2, '201\n': 2, '249\n': 2, '226\n': 2, '169\n': 2, '269\n': 2, '287\n': 2, '11\n': 1, '9\n': 1, '211\n': 1, '179\n': 1, '207\n': 1, '299\n': 1, '210\n': 1, '262\n': 1, '193\n': 1, '309\n': 1, '221\n': 1, '292\n': 1, '308\n': 1, '220\n': 1, '225\n': 1, '214\n': 1, '316\n': 1, '228\n': 1, '238\n': 1, '180\n': 1, '320\n': 1, '234\n': 1, '205\n': 1, '194\n': 1, '187\n': 1, '197\n': 1, '198\n': 1, '230\n': 1, '204\n': 1, '251\n': 1, '235\n': 1, '219\n': 1, '196\n': 1, '253\n': 1, '223\n': 1, '212\n': 1, '185\n': 1, '218\n': 1, '215\n': 1, '224\n': 1, '315\n': 1, '188\n': 1, '285\n': 1, '264\n': 1, '206\n': 1, '312\n': 1, '293\n': 1, '302\n': 1, '213\n': 1, '260\n': 1, '282\n': 1, '295\n': 1})
```

I need to parse its keys and their item values in order to be able to put the data in a graphs X and Y axis. Could you clear out my mind? I'm stuck!

Comment: What is that Counter()?

Comment: please provide [mcve] of your attempt before asking for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counter is also a dictionary so you can get the keys and values using .keys() and .values() functions.

```
c = Counter({'140\n': 3098, '139\n': 1543, '138\n': 1259, '137\n': 1135})
allkeys = [k for k in c.keys()]
allvals = [v for v in c.values()]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Below will give you a list of tuples of coordinates:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = {'140\n': 3098, '139\n': 1543, '138\n': 1259, '137\n': 1135, '136\n': 990, '135\n': 851, '134\n': 826, '133\n': 644, '132\n': 574, '131\n': 531, '144\n': 481, '130\n': 473, '129\n': 443, '128\n': 428, '126\n': 397, '127\n': 384, '125\n': 351, '124\n': 325, '123\n': 314, '121\n': 305, '111\n': 304, '118\n': 296, '114\n': 295, '122\n': 294, '117\n': 292, '116\n': 290, '119\n': 287, '120\n': 287, '113\n': 286, '115\n': 276, '112\n': 266, '110\n': 266, '109\n': 246, '101\n': 241, '106\n': 240, '98\n': 236, '102\n': 235, '107\n': 234, '93\n': 234, '104\n': 232, '100\n': 231, '103\n': 229, '108\n': 228, '97\n': 222, '105\n': 220, '96\n': 218, '99\n': 216, '143\n': 213, '94\n': 211, '90\n': 198, '95\n': 197, '91\n': 196, '92\n': 196, '83\n': 193, '88\n': 193, '86\n': 192, '87\n': 192, '89\n': 191, '81\n': 189, '84\n': 188, '77\n': 187, '80\n': 183, '85\n': 173, '79\n': 170, '82\n': 170, '75\n': 167, '74\n': 163, '70\n': 160, '142\n': 155, '78\n': 153, '72\n': 151, '71\n': 147, '76\n': 146, '68\n': 137, '65\n': 134, '141\n': 133, '73\n': 132, '62\n': 124, '66\n': 124, '57\n': 124, '63\n': 121, '69\n': 117, '59\n': 113, '56\n': 113, '67\n': 111, '60\n': 110, '61\n': 107, '58\n': 106, '51\n': 100, '22\n': 100, '25\n': 99, '24\n': 99, '48\n': 97, '23\n': 95, '64\n': 93, '52\n': 92, '53\n': 92, '45\n': 91, '20\n': 91, '55\n': 90, '54\n': 89, '50\n': 86, '49\n': 85, '34\n': 85, '36\n': 85, '21\n': 83, '29\n': 82, '26\n': 80, '47\n': 79, '27\n': 79, '30\n': 78, '40\n': 76, '31\n': 76, '46\n': 76, '35\n': 75, '32\n': 75, '37\n': 70, '39\n': 69, '19\n': 68, '28\n': 67, '41\n': 67, '43\n': 66, '148\n': 66, '33\n': 64, '38\n': 59, '42\n': 58, '44\n': 56, '164\n': 50, '18\n': 48, '17\n': 46, '163\n': 43, '168\n': 39, '147\n': 37, '161\n': 29, '162\n': 29, '16\n': 25, '167\n': 25, '146\n': 23, '15\n': 23, '145\n': 23, '156\n': 22, '152\n': 21, '159\n': 20, '160\n': 19, '157\n': 19, '158\n': 17, '151\n': 16, '280\n': 15, '166\n': 13, '150\n': 11, '172\n': 11, '14\n': 10, '149\n': 10, '155\n': 9, '165\n': 9, '154\n': 9, '153\n': 8, '284\n': 8, '13\n': 7, '12\n': 6, '279\n': 6, '273\n': 6, '216\n': 6, '170\n': 5, '248\n': 5, '278\n': 5, '254\n': 5, '174\n': 5, '10\n': 4, '176\n': 4, '283\n': 4, '272\n': 4, '277\n': 4, '263\n': 4, '276\n': 4, '175\n': 4, '250\n': 4, '183\n': 4, '245\n': 4, '246\n': 3, '281\n': 3, '266\n': 3, '240\n': 3, '237\n': 3, '190\n': 3, '208\n': 3, '275\n': 3, '257\n': 3, '232\n': 3, '270\n': 3, '274\n': 3, '229\n': 3, '233\n': 3, '255\n': 3, '241\n': 3, '271\n': 3, '171\n': 3, '227\n': 2, '199\n': 2, '222\n': 2, '209\n': 2, '288\n': 2, '259\n': 2, '304\n': 2, '286\n': 2, '184\n': 2, '268\n': 2, '242\n': 2, '265\n': 2, '296\n': 2, '217\n': 2, '256\n': 2, '191\n': 2, '290\n': 2, '303\n': 2, '173\n': 2, '307\n': 2, '200\n': 2, '231\n': 2, '301\n': 2, '261\n': 2, '186\n': 2, '201\n': 2, '249\n': 2, '226\n': 2, '169\n': 2, '269\n': 2, '287\n': 2, '11\n': 1, '9\n': 1, '211\n': 1, '179\n': 1, '207\n': 1, '299\n': 1, '210\n': 1, '262\n': 1, '193\n': 1, '309\n': 1, '221\n': 1, '292\n': 1, '308\n': 1, '220\n': 1, '225\n': 1, '214\n': 1, '316\n': 1, '228\n': 1, '238\n': 1, '180\n': 1, '320\n': 1, '234\n': 1, '205\n': 1, '194\n': 1, '187\n': 1, '197\n': 1, '198\n': 1, '230\n': 1, '204\n': 1, '251\n': 1, '235\n': 1, '219\n': 1, '196\n': 1, '253\n': 1, '223\n': 1, '212\n': 1, '185\n': 1, '218\n': 1, '215\n': 1, '224\n': 1, '315\n': 1, '188\n': 1, '285\n': 1, '264\n': 1, '206\n': 1, '312\n': 1, '293\n': 1, '302\n': 1, '213\n': 1, '260\n': 1, '282\n': 1, '295\n': 1}

coords = np.array([(int(i), int(j)) for i, j in x.items()])
plt.scatter(coords[:,0], coords[:,1])
plt.show()
```

Here I am ignoring counter and working directly with the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

```
dic = {'140\n': 3098, '139\n': 1543, '138\n': 1259, '137\n': 1135, '136\n': 990, '135\n': 851, '134\n': 826, '133\n': 644, '132\n': 574, '131\n': 531, '144\n': 481, '130\n': 473, '129\n': 443, '128\n': 428, '126\n': 397, '127\n': 384, '125\n': 351, '124\n': 325, '123\n': 314, '121\n': 305, '111\n': 304, '118\n': 296, '114\n': 295, '122\n': 294, '117\n': 292, '116\n': 290, '119\n': 287, '120\n': 287, '113\n': 286, '115\n': 276, '112\n': 266, '110\n': 266, '109\n': 246, '101\n': 241, '106\n': 240, '98\n': 236, '102\n': 235, '107\n': 234, '93\n': 234, '104\n': 232, '100\n': 231, '103\n': 229, '108\n': 228, '97\n': 222, '105\n': 220, '96\n': 218, '99\n': 216, '143\n': 213, '94\n': 211, '90\n': 198, '95\n': 197, '91\n': 196, '92\n': 196, '83\n': 193, '88\n': 193, '86\n': 192, '87\n': 192, '89\n': 191, '81\n': 189, '84\n': 188, '77\n': 187, '80\n': 183, '85\n': 173, '79\n': 170, '82\n': 170, '75\n': 167, '74\n': 163, '70\n': 160, '142\n': 155, '78\n': 153, '72\n': 151, '71\n': 147, '76\n': 146, '68\n': 137, '65\n': 134, '141\n': 133, '73\n': 132, '62\n': 124, '66\n': 124, '57\n': 124, '63\n': 121, '69\n': 117, '59\n': 113, '56\n': 113, '67\n': 111, '60\n': 110, '61\n': 107, '58\n': 106, '51\n': 100, '22\n': 100, '25\n': 99, '24\n': 99, '48\n': 97, '23\n': 95, '64\n': 93, '52\n': 92, '53\n': 92, '45\n': 91, '20\n': 91, '55\n': 90, '54\n': 89, '50\n': 86, '49\n': 85, '34\n': 85, '36\n': 85, '21\n': 83, '29\n': 82, '26\n': 80, '47\n': 79, '27\n': 79, '30\n': 78, '40\n': 76, '31\n': 76, '46\n': 76, '35\n': 75, '32\n': 75, '37\n': 70, '39\n': 69, '19\n': 68, '28\n': 67, '41\n': 67, '43\n': 66, '148\n': 66, '33\n': 64, '38\n': 59, '42\n': 58, '44\n': 56, '164\n': 50, '18\n': 48, '17\n': 46, '163\n': 43, '168\n': 39, '147\n': 37, '161\n': 29, '162\n': 29, '16\n': 25, '167\n': 25, '146\n': 23, '15\n': 23, '145\n': 23, '156\n': 22, '152\n': 21, '159\n': 20, '160\n': 19, '157\n': 19, '158\n': 17, '151\n': 16, '280\n': 15, '166\n': 13, '150\n': 11, '172\n': 11, '14\n': 10, '149\n': 10, '155\n': 9, '165\n': 9, '154\n': 9, '153\n': 8, '284\n': 8, '13\n': 7, '12\n': 6, '279\n': 6, '273\n': 6, '216\n': 6, '170\n': 5, '248\n': 5, '278\n': 5, '254\n': 5, '174\n': 5, '10\n': 4, '176\n': 4, '283\n': 4, '272\n': 4, '277\n': 4, '263\n': 4, '276\n': 4, '175\n': 4, '250\n': 4, '183\n': 4, '245\n': 4, '246\n': 3, '281\n': 3, '266\n': 3, '240\n': 3, '237\n': 3, '190\n': 3, '208\n': 3, '275\n': 3, '257\n': 3, '232\n': 3, '270\n': 3, '274\n': 3, '229\n': 3, '233\n': 3, '255\n': 3, '241\n': 3, '271\n': 3, '171\n': 3, '227\n': 2, '199\n': 2, '222\n': 2, '209\n': 2, '288\n': 2, '259\n': 2, '304\n': 2, '286\n': 2, '184\n': 2, '268\n': 2, '242\n': 2, '265\n': 2, '296\n': 2, '217\n': 2, '256\n': 2, '191\n': 2, '290\n': 2, '303\n': 2, '173\n': 2, '307\n': 2, '200\n': 2, '231\n': 2, '301\n': 2, '261\n': 2, '186\n': 2, '201\n': 2, '249\n': 2, '226\n': 2, '169\n': 2, '269\n': 2, '287\n': 2, '11\n': 1, '9\n': 1, '211\n': 1, '179\n': 1, '207\n': 1, '299\n': 1, '210\n': 1, '262\n': 1, '193\n': 1, '309\n': 1, '221\n': 1, '292\n': 1, '308\n': 1, '220\n': 1, '225\n': 1, '214\n': 1, '316\n': 1, '228\n': 1, '238\n': 1, '180\n': 1, '320\n': 1, '234\n': 1, '205\n': 1, '194\n': 1, '187\n': 1, '197\n': 1, '198\n': 1, '230\n': 1, '204\n': 1, '251\n': 1, '235\n': 1, '219\n': 1, '196\n': 1, '253\n': 1, '223\n': 1, '212\n': 1, '185\n': 1, '218\n': 1, '215\n': 1, '224\n': 1, '315\n': 1, '188\n': 1, '285\n': 1, '264\n': 1, '206\n': 1, '312\n': 1, '293\n': 1, '302\n': 1, '213\n': 1, '260\n': 1, '282\n': 1, '295\n': 1}

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([(int(a.split('\n')[0]), b) for a, b in dic.items()])
plt.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1])
```

Comment: I think this will give an error. The list comprehension will fail.

Comment: it will still fail. I think the correct version is `data = np.array([(int(a), int(b)) for a, b in dic.items()])` . I just tested it.

Comment: Sorry it looks like your new version will indeed work.

Comment: splitting the string is not strictly necessary, and makes the code look uglier, so yours is the prettier version :)